# Receive only 5 reputation when answer is upvoted

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

Actually it's not me but some other guy's SO account:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049264/nejat?tab=reputation

Here is the reputation change for the events from the post.

[image]

and here is the post: [How to accomplish drop down word suggestions in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248606/how-to-accomplish-this-in-qt-word-suggestions-as-drop-down/24248729#24248729) .

As you can see:

- It's an answer.
- It has not been accepted yet, hence there is no **+15** reputation
- There is a **+5** upvote for the answer

I've checked the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and  didn't find the answer.

Comment: From that help center link: "You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below.". He hit the rep cap.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The user hit the reputation cap. He was at 195 on upvotes, so the last upvote only netted +5.

You can only ever earn +200 from votes in total; this means that any upvote that would put you *over* that cap is truncated. If the user had been at 198 due to a downvote, then the capped vote would net you +2, etc.

Comment: Pardon me, though I don't know that guy but won't it be unfair to him? Can another +5 reputation due to him be refunded to him tomorrow?

Comment: @Tay2510: No, upvotes over the rep cap are gone. That is what the cap means. Accepts and bonuses are not capped.

Comment: @Tay2510: This applies to *everyone* and gives newer people a chance to gain a place in the league tables. Otherwise Jon Skeet would just earn 1000 points per day from old answers alone.